# ArcGIS Find task performance over SDE

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

We are having a problem in our Search feature for our app. We are using arcgis published REST services and SDE database. When we try to do our search manually using the REST url, it takes roughly 9 minutes for it to finish. Although it is searching an LSD layer, i don't think it should take that much time.

My question is: Is there anything we can do to improve the performance of the find task?

We already did the compress, analyze and rebuild indexes in our SDE database.

Thanks.

Comment: The performance issue is hard to pinpoint without knowing some more information about the server specs and your system architecture.  Is the server hosting many other GIS services?  Is the service publically available (so we can test against it)?

Comment: The database vendor, the layout of the table, the list of indexes created on columns in the table, and the actual query are all really required for any assistance on this matter.

Comment: @ew_gis unfortunately it not publicly available. "hosting many other GIS services" does this mean multiple published map service? If yes, there around 15 map services running on the server, we are also looking on bringing some of it down. We have Windows Server 2008 R2, 24gb ram, Xeon(R) 3.07GHz, ArcGIS 10.1 and SDE is running in SQL Server 2012.